# Swift determine if you have enough cells to cover the whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, height, screen, uitableview

Is there an easy way do determine if you have enough `TableViewCells` to cover the whole screen? Like the whole screen space reserved for the `TableView` is covered in `cells`.

I know you can add up the height of each `cell` and the height of group `headers` and the `StatusBar` and any other elements in the screen and see if the sum if less than the height of the screen of the used device. But is there a more elegant and easier way to know?

Comment: the better way to handle this using screen percentage , and distribute using your status bar , header , footer and cell , then automatically it covers screen completely in any device

Comment: As `UITableView` is derived from `UIScrollView`, you can always get its `.contentSize` after having call `layoutIfNeed`. Then compare it with your screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count it by something like,

```
  let tableViewLastPoint = self.yourTableView.tableFooterView!.frame.origin.y + self.yourTableView.tableFooterView!.frame.size.height
```

then compare that if `tableViewLastPoint` is greater than your screen's height then you have cell that requires more height then screen, else cells are not required full screen!

In this case you should initialize your `tableview's footerview with zero frame` like,

```
  self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectZero)
```